# Вывод сообщений через определенное время

Tags: javascript

Добрый день!

```js
 function func(phrase) {
      console.log( phrase );
    }
    
    setTimeout(func, 1000, "text1"); 
    setTimeout(func, 2000, "text2"); 
    setTimeout(func, 3000, "text3");
```

Comment: а чем не устраивает приведенный код?

Answer (score 1):

```js
 function func(phrase) {
      console.log( phrase );
    }
    
    setTimeout(func, 1000, "text1"); 
    setTimeout(func, 3000, "text2"); 
    setTimeout(func, 6000, "text3");
```

Такой вариант вам подходит?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант посчитать самому:

```
function func(phrase) {
  console.log( phrase );
}

setTimeout(func, 1000, "text1"); 
setTimeout(func, 3000, "text2"); 
setTimeout(func, 6000, "text3");
```

Или можно усложнить, зато всё считается само и можно добавлять сколько угодно значений.

```js
var data = {
    'test1' : 1000,
    'test2' : 2000,
    'test3' : 3000
};

var delayTime = 0;
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(text, i) {
    delayTime += data[text];
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(text);
    }, delayTime);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - используйте цепочки [обещаний](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (в данном примере это может быть избыточно, но научиться можно на этом примере, чтобы потом применять)

```js
function func(phrase, delay) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(phrase);
      resolve();
    }, delay);
  })
}

func('text1', 1000).then(function() {
  return func('text2', 2000);
}).then(function() {
  return func('text3', 3000);
});
```

Приведенный код работает во всех современных браузерах. Для старых браузеров можно использовать [полифилл](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise) или [jQuery.Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)

Comment: в Promise лучше было один setTimeout вынуть, чтобы не смешивать ожидание с самой функцией